# Optional route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

```
    [Route("v2/Actual")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MeasurementActualAggregatedResultViewModel>> GetActualsWithHierarchy(int calendarStartYear = 0, int calendarEndYear = 0, string managementSystem = "amspe")
    {
    
      var result = ...
    
      return result;
    } 



 // I want to make this recognise ....v2/Actual?measurementId=1&calendarMonth=12&calendarYear=2020
[Route("v2/Actual{measurementId}{calendarMonth}{calendarYear}")]     
[HttpGet]
public async Task<MeasurementActualAggregatedResultViewModel> GetActual(int measurementId, int calendarMonth, int calendarYear)
{
    return null;
}
```

I have an API above that I would like to configure the route to be as above. I struggle to find an answer around Route parameter specification where there is a question mark.

What should go into the Route(...) value?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Also, those are route parameters in the `[Route(...)]`, but your comment refers to query parameters.

Comment: ASP.net Core. Sorry I meant Route parameters.

Comment: Can you edit your sample URL to show how you expect the route parameters to work?

Comment: Hi, I will accept your answer for what it is worth, but my question should have been worded differently and the answer I am looking for is different (of which I have already found a different solution, and therefore I won't edit this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Route like below, the query string in request url will match the parameter in action by default, no need add the query string as Route parameter:

```
[Route("v2/Actual")]     
[HttpGet]
public async Task<MeasurementActualAggregatedResultViewModel> GetActual(int measurementId, int calendarMonth, int calendarYear)
{
    return null;
}
```